How to convert Arc<Enum> to Arc<enum_inner>?
struct ServiceA{
    field_a: String,
}

struct ServiceB{
    field_b: i32,
}

impl ServiceA {
    pub async fn init(self: Arc<Self>){
        tokio::spawn(async move { self.daemon_task().await});
    }

    async fn daemon_task(&self){
        //do loop task
    }
}

enum Service {
    A(ServiceA),
    B(ServiceB)
}


I have arc_obj: Arc<Service>. How can I downgrade it to an Arc<ServiceA> when arc_obj is Service::A?
I use enum dispatch and tokio, so I wrap a Service object in Arc to use it in multiple threads. ServiceA has init to start a daemon task and it wants an Arc<ServiceA>. How can I get one?

This might be the case where you should use normal dynamic dispatch, and not enum dispath. I don't think it could work for you.

Relevant: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/anyway-to-get-ref-map-functionality-for-rc/86902

My case maybe a common case. Is it possible to implement such functionality by unsafe code? however I coundn't found a related crate in crates.io.

No, it's not possible, in most cases Service and ServiceA don't have the same layout (the enum has to discriminate the variants in addition to storing the value), and even if they do, that's just an optimization that is not guaranteed.

You could change the enum to A(Arc<ServiceA>) and similar for B.

What @SvenMarnach wrote is probably the way to go, simple and effective. Note that after wrapping all variants in Arc, you no longer need to wrap the enum itself, because the enum will get Arc properties (cheap cloning) simply by deriving Clone.

Thank you all, I will try 'A(Arc)', it seems work for me.
